# could not load assembly 'system.data.entity, version 4.2.0.0,

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I have this error message

> could not load assembly 'system.data.entity, version 4.2.0.0,
>   culture=neutral,publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of it's
>   dependencies. the system cannot find the file specified

and I cannot use the entity framework at all. 
it happened after uninstalling June 2011 CTP from my computer, and I have no idea what to do. I reinstalled the visual studio again and with no help. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: When do you get the exception?

Comment: i got it when i tried to add an .edmx file which represent the connection to the db by edm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

after reinstalling visual studio i found another insatnce of the CTP as part of sql server in the add/remove programs, after removing that all was well.

Comment: To clarify, this package is called `SQL Server Data Framework Tools June 2011 CTP`. Thanks for your solution, it helped me too!

Comment: Spot on! This helped me too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. After much frustration, I eventually resorted to re-installing the  June 2011 CTP. Not ideal, but at least I can get on with my work...

Comment: I think for now I solved the issuu, there was another CTP hiding between my sql instances in the add/remove programs. After uninstalling it and doing a full and complete uninstall of visual studio and reinstalling it, it's working again. thx all.

Comment: the problem i had with ctp that i didn't like working with, because it had a bug generating a code item that make the dbcontext.