# Can't use .edmx model when switching from VS 2010 to 2012

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

The project I'm working on was originally developed to target .Net 4.0. However, I wanted to start using ENUMS in the EDMX model I use for code generation. I made the mistake of using .NET 4.2 June 2011 CTP as an intermediate solution (before upgrading to VS2012, and be able to use .NET 4.5).
Now that open the solution in VS2012, have targeted all projects to build against .NET 4.5 and uninstalled the June 2011 CTP, I cannot properly open the .edmx file. I only get XML text. Moreover, if I try to build the projects/solution, I get errors saying 'The type or namespace  does not exist...'.
Last but not least if I start a *new* project and want to add a *new* .edmx file, I get the error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.2.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified
```

I already repaired, then uninstalled, then installed VS2012, but these issues remain.

Comment: @bitbonk Yes I already did that! But to no avail. Should I uninstall/reinstall ALL my VS versions? I have 2010 and 2012 installed right now. I uninstalled/reinstalled 2012 too.

Comment: So you even have this issue when you create a new **solution**? .NET 4.5 is an in-place update of .NET 4 (it modifies .NET 4 components) and the June 2011 CTP probably was too. Maybe something went wrong here.

Comment: @bitbonk after Googling some more I found the solution, on SO no less! See my answer below. Thanks for helping anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out you not only need to uninstall the EF June 2011 CTP but also the `SQL Server Data Framework Tools June 2011 CTP`. Special thanks to @mashtagidi: [could not load assembly 'system.data.entity, version 4.2.0.0,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565650/could-not-load-assembly-system-data-entity-version-4-2-0-0)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, uninstalling the SQL Server Data Framework Tools June 2011 CTP removes the edmx design surface from Visual Studio 2010 and as yet I have been unable to restore it.